# Javascript error productSidebar.js Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, javascript, sidebar

i'm using Magento 2.3.3, and in my catalog's console i found this error

[image]

in pub/static/ there's no a folder named "version.." but if you skip that folder you can find directly "frontend/AtelierVM/.../productSideBar.js". I'm in developer mode, so i tried to change it to product mode but nothing changed. 
how can i fix it or how can i remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all files in pub/static and deploy again. Also unmerge and unminify js in admin.

Comment: i tried it but nothing changed, and i have same error when i switch to production mode and magento try to search some other static files in that folder.